# Facebook chat plugin not displaying on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

The instructions are extremely simple and easy
I have generated the following code through the ***"Customer Chat Plugin Setup"***

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="124030157608968">
</div>
```

but the chat icon does not appear.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can You try to change 
`js.src` attribute to:

```js
js.src = 
"https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12"
```

This can be a temporary issue [Live Chat Disappeared](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/569043113508384/?comment_id=569619380117424) @Nov 19, 2018, 10:07 AM

Comment: Hello, It solved it, but I just checked my website and the chat plugin has disappeared again :O

Comment: Today it works... So looks like it is something from facebook...

However thank you again!

Comment: Half an year later it doesn't work again. Couldn't find any information about this.